# Does using JMS in the middle of a Apache Camel route guarantee delivery?

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms

According to [Apache Camel documentation](http://camel.apache.org/guaranteed-delivery.html), "Camel supports the Guaranteed Delivery from the EIP patterns using among others the following components: ... JMS."

I'm trying to understand if this means I can use JMS in the middle of a multi-component route to "guarantee delivery."

For example, I have some routes that looks like this:

```
from("rest://post:someRestRoute")
    // blah blah
    .to("jms:queue:someQueue");

from("jms:queue:someQueue")
    // blah blah
    .to("spring-ws:someAddress")
    .to("someOtherRoute");
```

Does using JMS in the middle of a multi-component route have any benefits? Camel is writing to and reading from the queue, and the queue is running on the same computer and same JVM, so Camel is only guaranteeing delivery to itself, which seems redundant.

For example,

1. A message is POSTed to `someRestRoute`.
2. The message is queued and persisted on `someQueue`.
3. The message is immediately dequeued.
4. The message is sent to a webservice at `someAddress`.

As I understand it, as far as the JMS broker is concerned the message is "delivered" the moment it's successfully dequeued; it doesn't matter if `spring-ws:someAddress` throws an exception. I suppose this might be helpful if Camel crashed *immediately* after step 2, but I was hoping to guarantee delivery to `someAddress`.

Does using JMS in the middle of a multi-component route have any benefits? Can it be used to "guarantee delivery" to `someAddress` in the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if your JMS queue is defined to persist messages. Then in case your route/application/server stopped before picking message, it will be in the queue until processed next time when route starts.
If you do not need persistence then there is no reason to have JMS.
Camel can be set to retry delivery to the endpoint in case of failure.

But, if you need persistence JMS is the best (if not only one) way to do it.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why the message would ever stay on the queue for more than a few milliseconds. The application is already processing the message, so why place it on a queue to immediately take it off again?

Comment: h-m-m-m... let say you need a guarantee delivery and in some situation message was placed, but not picked because many requestes coming, JVM runs fullGC or crushed, server rebooted, power went off etc. Then you need a persistence

Comment: Another and more important case is for clustered environment. if it is direct: direct-vm: seda: kind of endpoint it runs in one JVM or CamelContext). Having JMS in between allows to process message in any numbers of other servers.

Comment: you are always welcome. Generally speaking main porposes of JMS are: 1. decouple publishing from processing. 2. deliver same message to multiple consumers (if it is a Topic or consumers use filters on Queue) 3. Guaranteed delivery. If nothing of it is a case and all can be processed straight forward in one JVM/CamelConext then there is no reason to have JMS in between. Performance will be better and less resources needed, such as IBM MQ, ActiveMQ etc...